# How can I mock MatDialog in order to have openDialog[index].id defined?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, mat-dialog

This is the code in my component, but since **openDialogs** is readable only, I'm struggling to define an array with one MatDialogRef element

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._dialogInstance = this.dialog.getDialogById(this.dialog.openDialogs[0].id);
    this._dialogInstance.addPanelClass(this._SCAN_GRAPHER_PANEL_CLASS);
     ...
}
```

in the test

```
matDialog = MockService(MatDialog);
const dialogInstance = MockInstance(MatDialogRef) as unknown as MatDialogRef<any, any>;
Object.assign(matDialog.openDialogs, [{ id: '0' }]);
spyOn(matDialog, 'getDialogById').and.returnValue(dialogInstance);

await TestBed.configureTestingModule({ ....})
....
```

and I'm getting the following error (on the line where I'm using Object.assign)

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: You can mock the `getDialogById` method to return the dialog you want.

Comment: you can hack it a bit by removing or modifying type of your matDialog `matDialog: any = MockService(MatDialog);`

Answer (score 0):

I sorted as following

```
const dialogInstance = {
      addPanelClass: (panelClasses: string | string[]) => dialogInstance,
      removePanelClass: (panelClasses: string | string[]) => dialogInstance
    } as unknown as MatDialogRef<any, any>;

    (matDialog.openDialogs as any) = [{ id: '0' }];
    matDialog.getDialogById.and.returnValue(dialogInstance);
```

The main thing was to wrap `matDialog.openDialogs as any` so I was able to set the id of the dialog